# Multisite Subdirectory with same domain subdomain

Tags: multisite, htaccess, directory, subdomains, network-admin

I currently have a multi-site install on a subdomain, let's call it example.domain.com. Generally, I want users to have subdirectory sites, such as example.domain.com/site1. However, in a few cases, I would like certain sites to appear as a subdomain rather than a subdirectory. For example, example.domain.com/site1 should be site1.domain.com.

I have installed the plugin "WordPress MU Domain Mapping" and have not had success. I mapped the NS and created CNAME records to the site.

For example:

1. site1.domain.com is mapped to example.domain.com (CNAME points to example.domain.com) and NS updated to match those of example.domain.com
2. In the site settings, I make sure the primary site is set to site1.domain.com and I wait a few hours to try to allow the DNS settings to update
3. Going to site1.domain.com simply redirects me to example.domain.com. It does not serve content from example.domain.com/site1. If I type site1.domain.com/site1, I am redirected to example.domain.com/site1.

This is not the behavior I am looking for. If a user visits site1.example.com/account, I want them to stay on site1.example.com (which is serving content from example.domain.com/site1/account).

Something to note: example.domain.com is hosted via Google Cloud while domain.com is hosted via another webhost. This is why I have to update the nameservers from my example above.

I recently tired the following in my htaccess.conf, but it doesn't work either:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?site1.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.domain.com/site1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong or if this will even work.

Thank you all so much for any suggestions!